# What is microsoft traffic manager analog in amazon infrastructure?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the Microsoft [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/traffic-manager/) analog in AWS for EC2 instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS [Route53 Health Checks and DNS failover](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) are effectively Azure Traffic Manager.  The big difference is that Traffic Manager will happily provide a service that covers [Azure endpoints and non-Azure endpoints](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-traffic-manager-external-endpoints-and-weighted-round-robin-via-powershell/) where AWS can only cover services hosted on AWS.

Comment: Do you have a reference that indicates AWS R53 health checks can't be used with non-AWS endpoints? It appears to be pretty platform-agnostic to me?

Comment: ^^ [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html): "In a failover configuration, Amazon Route 53 checks the health of the registered EC2 instances for the load balancer to determine whether they are available."

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: This is no longer true, you can see their pricing page includes [non-AWS endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/#Health_Checks)

Answer (score 1):

The combination of Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer, and Route 53 would give you roughly the capabilities of the Azure traffic Manager.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on how to do such thing?

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com is your best resource - loads of docs - also, lots of youtube videos giving a decent overview of all of their services.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Route 53 also covers services hosted outside AWS

Answer (score 0):

Technically, AWS does not yet have an alternative for Azure Traffic Manager, as of May 2023.

Azure Traffic Manager performs failover or load distribution across multiple regions.

As of May 2023, AWS has these 2 products that can cater to the requirement of cross-region failover and load distribution.

1. Route 53
2. Global Accelerator

Route 53 must be set up with complex health checks and cloud-watch alarms to achieve the multi-region failover functionality which is similar to that of Azure Traffic Manager.

AWS Global Accelerator is a tool for speeding up content delivery to the end user by serving it from the nearest host. It acts as a proxy for the application instances and routes all incoming requests through the AWS network. Due to this, the Global Accelerator will incur hourly running costs regardless of whether there is any incoming request to the application.

**Conclusion**

Azure Traffic Manager is a straightforward and effective tool for multi-region traffic routing.

AWS has 2 products that cater to similar business requirements, but neither of those is identical in functionality or simplicity or running expense to Azure Traffic Manager.